# Navigating through a webpages that uses function instead of url with Jsoup

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup

```html
<div class="pb_ft clearfix" style="width:500px;clear:both;margin-top:50px;">
  <div class="turn_page" id="list_navigator" style="margin-left:200px;">
    <ol style="width:980px;">
      <li style="width:100px;border:0">12129 Pages</li>
      <li class="turn_pre"><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.goPre();return false;">Last Page</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(1,12129);return false;">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(2,12129);return false;">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(3,12129);return false;">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(5,12129);return false;">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(6,12129);return false;">6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.go(7,12129);return false;">7</a></li>
      <li class="turn_next"><a href="#" onclick="PageContext.PageNav.goNext();return false;">Next Page</a></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <!--Next Page-->
</div>
```

It uses a href = "#" and then a function  "PageContext.PageNav.go(2, 12128).

It appears that 12128 total pages are loaded by calling a JavaScript function.

What is the best way to navigate through these webpages? Should I better simulate a button click or I could invoke the website's function to make it flip pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup is an **HTML parser** and isn't a browser. With that being said, it's still possible to look at what is being returned in the url after you've clicked on a menu option.

If it's something predictable you can append the needed params to the URL to grab with Jsoup. If not, you're going to have to use something like Selenium to cycle through the menu then parse each page with Jsoup.

You could also try and disable Javascript in your browser to see how the website handles it. It could take you to a nav that doesn't use js. It's worth a shot.

Comment: I tried to use selenium to crawl the website, but it is really slow. Most of the time is taken by selenium to click the button. And I used nearly 5 hours to crawl the 12 thousand-page. Is there any other software that you would recommend?

Comment: I've never used HTMLUnit but it seems to be a little more lightwight and faster from what I've read. You can read about it here and perhaps give it a test to see if this solution may work better for your needs. - https://www.guru99.com/selenium-with-htmlunit-driver-phantomjs.html